# Error while updating feature information to geoserver using OL3

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, georeferencing, wfs-t

I am trying to update feature information of wfs feature to geoserver using WFST in ol3. I am getting the below error in the response

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
<ows:ExceptionText> 
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: 1178724.6835985 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
Parsing failed for LineString: org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: 
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: 1178724.6835985 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException: 
1178724.6835985 outside of (-180.0,180.0)
1178724.6835985 outside of (-180.0,180.0)</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

And my request is

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><Update typeName="undefined" xmlns:feature="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/geowebmap_ws"><Property><Name>the_geom</Name><Value><MultiLineString xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326"><lineStringMember><LineString srsName="EPSG:4326"><posList>1178724.6835985 8865818.20524869 1179426.69118129 8864805.19788247 1180462.9028373 8863781.32573395 1185077.23512065 8860641.8489268 1186685.37344036 8858025.82976121 1188893.85395699 8856311.50960299 1192110.55978526 8852515.52609889 1192563.64100789 8851714.02576518 1193798.31753863 8845947.67614209 1194366.28358949 8845081.20975355</posList></LineString></lineStringMember></MultiLineString></Value></Property><Property><Name>TYPE</Name><Value>primary</Value></Property><Property><Name>NAME</Name><Value>Thanjavur - Mannargudy - Thiruthuraipoondi - Vedaranyam - Kodiakkarai Road</Value></Property><Property><Name>ONEWAY</Name><Value>test</Value></Property><Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"><FeatureId fid="tn_highways.15747"/></Filter></Update></Transaction>
```

Comment: the coordinates are not in 4326 but in a projected CRS (3857 maybe?)

Comment: Yes is that the issue. So do i need to project it to 4326? and then sent to geoserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the part where you lie about your coordinate system to something nearer the truth.

```
srsName="EPSG:4326"
```

should be something like (change it to match your actual reference system)

```
srsName="EPSG:3857"
```